# NSURLConnection. How do I grab just HTTP header information?

Tags: iphone, nsurlrequest

NSURLRequest + NSHTTPURLResponse is clearly the way to role. How do I just grab the header info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling allHeaderFields on your NSHTTPURLResponse will return them as a dictionary.

```
[response allHeaderFields]
```

where response is your NSHTTPURLResponse object.

Comment: Additionally, using an NSMutableURLRequest and calling [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"] will result in less bandwidth being used (if the server supports it)

Comment: rpetrich,
This is the critical bit I was looking for. I DON'T want to grab the entire message body of the URL which is many gigabytes. Thanks so much for the pointer.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score -2):

⌘-doubleclick on a reference to "NSHTTPURLResponse" in your code, and it will show you the documentation.

Comment: That doesn't show the documentation, it just links to the header file with the method signature.